# Roku screen hangs for 10 seconds after an ad

Tags: roku, brightscript

I m having an issue with my roku channel:

I have a rowlist with a custom component, let's call it RowlistComponent.xml and brs, that usually take less than 40ms to render.

When you select an item, it brings you to a detail screen and from there you can play a video. When playing a video, you get a preroll ad, that I play with show_ads().

The issue is that when the ad is finished, and the RAF player gets dismissed, cells from the rowlist (that is not even visible at this point) get redrawn and this time the channel hangs for 10-12 seconds because cells each take 1.6-2 seconds to be drawn.
To be clear, if my rowlist does not have a custom component (.itemComponentName), there is no lag.

Is there a known issue, or a workaround that would allow me to fix this lag?

Comment: Discussion on this happening at https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=99107

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have some heavy calculations inside of your **itemComponent**. Check whether you are not doing too much processing in **focusPercent** observer (if there is one).

Comment: Hi Eugene, I have done my testing with an empty component (no children, empty init and empty focusPercent functions)